# C# LDAP: Authenticationtype.Secure makes dn-syntax wrong

Tags: c#, authentication, ldap

I need to add a new user to a group with my ldap-system.

```
 public bool AddMemberToGroup(string user, string group)
    {
        user = "cn=" + user + ",ou=People" + uri;
        group = "cn=" + group + ",ou=groups";
        this.ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ip +"/" + "cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=my,dc=own,dc=path-to-ldap,dc=de", "admin", "adminPW");
        this.ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        try
        {
            this.ldapConnection.Properties["member"].Add(user);

            this.ldapConnection.CommitChanges();
            this.ldapConnection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In the above code snippet, I get the error, that the dn-syntax is invalid. When I change the `AuthenticationTypes` to `Anonymous`, I get the error, that `CommitChanges` needs authentication.

So I've got two alternatives:

1. No authentication, but then: How can I add a User to a group
2. Authenticate, but then: How is my syntax wrong? Could it be, that the server is unavailable?

Comment: If the dn syntax is wrong, so you won't be able to add any entry in that group whatever you put in Authenticationtype.Secure. Just fix the dn. What does `uri` look like ? The dn syntax is good in `cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=my,dc=own,dc=path-to-ldap,dc=de`, however if you actually use the variable `group` to retrieve the entry, you need to fix how is built its dn, currently the base dn (uri) is missing so you need to append it as you do for `user`. That also means that `uri` must begin with a comma like in `,dc=example=com`.

Comment: Another thing you should do is "dn-escaping" these dn components (user and group) as described in [RFC 2253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt) , see *2.4. Converting an AttributeValue from ASN.1 to a String*

Comment: You don't normally need to specify a server when you bind to AD - you can do a server-less bind by just using: "LDAP://cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=my,dc=own,dc=path-to-ldap,dc=de".  If you do need to specify a particular server (really don't do this unless you **have** to) then use the server name, not its IP address.  Hard-coded IP addresses will bite you in the backside.

Comment: (Cont'd) Secure means use SSPI for binding (akin to Negotiate).  I think Kerberos won't work for IP addresses, so if NTLM is disabled, it's not going to work